# Django NoReverseMatch not a valid view function

Tags: django

Django 1.11

I keep getting a NoReverseMatch error
Reverse for 'menu_menuitem' not found. 'menu_menuitem' is not a valid view function or battern name

Comment: post your urls.py for the menu_menuitem

Answer (score 0):

for `Category` model

```
@models.permalink
   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return ('show_category', (), { 'category_slug': self.slug })
```

for `MenuItem`model

```
@models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('show_menuitem', (), { 'menuitem_slug': self.slug })
```